# I'd like for the variables that talks about grandad to say that he's old but it says he's not old. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: python, function

```
name1 = 'homer'
age1 = 40
show1 = 'simpsons'

name2 = 'peter'
age2 = 40
show2 = 'family guy'

name3 = 'grandad'
age3 = 68
show3 = 'boondocks'

def tv_shows(name, age, show):
    age = (age1,age2,age3)
    for age in age:
        if age >= 66:
            return name +"?, he's old"
        else:
            if age <= 66:
                return name +"?, he's not old"



tv_shows(name1, age1, show1)
tv_shows(name2, age2, show2)
tv_shows(name3, age3, show3)
```

I'd like for the variables that talks about grandad to say that he's old but it says he's not old. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some unnecessary code in you code, here is a cleaner version:

```
name1 = 'homer'
age1 = 40
show1 = 'simpsons'

name2 = 'peter'
age2 = 40
show2 = 'family guy'

name3 = 'grandad'
age3 = 68
show3 = 'boondocks'

def tv_shows(name, age, show):
    if age >= 66:
        print(f"{name.title()}? He's old")
    elif age <= 66:
        print(f"{name.title()}? He's not old")

tv_shows(name1, age1, show1)
tv_shows(name2, age2, show2)
tv_shows(name3, age3, show3)
```

Output:

```
Homer? He's not old
Peter? He's not old
Grandad? He's old
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the age references in the function.

```
name1 = 'homer'
age1 = 40
show1 = 'simpsons'

name2 = 'peter'
age2 = 40
show2 = 'family guy'

name3 = 'grandad'
age3 = 68
show3 = 'boondocks'

def tv_shows(name, age, show):
    if age >= 66:
        return name +"?, he's old"
    else:
        if age <= 66:
            return name +"?, he's not old"



print(tv_shows(name1, age1, show1))
print(tv_shows(name2, age2, show2))
print(tv_shows(name3, age3, show3))
```

If you have any questions, just let me know with a comment.

Comment: @JimmyCarloss: why was  the age reference preventing it from printing the desired outcome? Thank you

Comment: Good question! You passed to the function the variable age, here 68. Python was all ready to use it, but then BAM you tell python that age is now a tuple of (40,40,68). It then goes through each age in turn. The 40 will get to the first "he's not that old, then return with that as its output, ending the function.